# How to make a Mutlithreded idhttp calls to do work on a StringList

Tags: multithreading, http, delphi, delphi-xe8

i am new to Threads, i have a List contains a strings. My goal is to make multiple threads do work to this List, this codes only for a single thread because i'm learning currently, however i get AV when i press start Button.

```
type
  TDemoThread = class(TThread)
  private
    procedure Abort;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    List: TStringList;
  end;

procedure TfrmMain.StartButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  List: Tstrings;
begin
  for i := 0 to memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    List := TStringList.Create;
    List.Add(memo1.Lines.Strings[i]);
  end;

  Thread := TDemoThread.Create(True);
  Thread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  Thread.Start;
end;

procedure TDemoThread.Execute;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  i: integer;
  X: Tstrings;
begin
  inherited;
  if Terminated then
    Exit;

  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  X := TStringList.Create;
  lHTTP.ReadTimeout := 30000;
  lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;

  for i := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
    try
      X.Text := lHTTP.Get('https://instagram.com/' + List.Strings[i]);
      S := ExtractDelimitedString(X.Text);
      X.Clear;
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          frmMain.Memo2.Lines.Add(List.Strings[i] + ' : ' + S);
        end);
    finally
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Suggestion: do not use TStringList unless you really need to use all the extended functionality it offers. Because that functionality makes it slow. If all you need is a dumb accumulator - then use a much faster `TList<string>` - or perhaps a `TThreadList<string>` instead. Then use `TTimer` on your form to catch-up your memo to that list 2 or 3 times per second.  /// 

Also I suggest you to look into a thirdparty library - http://otl.17slon.com/tutorials.htm - if you want to invest more time into multithreading. See Parrallel-For and ForJoin primitives there for this your task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd avoid updating the form from the threads themselves. Threads are data generators here, not GUI managers. So let them separate their concerns.

I'd make all the threads accumulate the results into the same shared container and then make a GUI thread to poll that container instead. Human eyes are slow and Windows GUI is slow too, so you should not update your GUI more often than 2 or 3 times per second. It would only waste CPU load and blur the form into being unreadable.

Another thing would be to avoid using slow `TStringList` unless its extra functionality (which makes it slow) is required. The regular `TList<string>` is more than enough as a dumb container and is faster.

```
type 
  TDemoThread = class;

  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
  private
    Fetchers: TThreadList<TDemoThread>;
    Data:     TThreadList<string>;

    property inProcess: Boolean read ... write SetInProcess;
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
    procedure BeforeDestruction; override;
  ....
  end;

  // this demo makes each thread per each line - that is actually a bad design
  // one better use a thread pool working over the same queue and only have
  // 20-40 worker threads for all the URLs
  TDemoThread = class(TThread)
  private
    URL: string;  
    List: TThreadList<string>;
    Tracker: TThreadList<TDemoThread>;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

procedure TfrmMain.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  while TThreadList.Count > 0 do
    Sleep(100);

  FreeAndNil( Fetchers );
  Data.Free;

  inherited;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.AfterConstruction;
begin
  Fetchers := TThreadList<TDemoThread>.Create;
  Data :=     TThreadList<string>.Create; 
  inherited;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.StartButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  List: Tstrings;
  worker: TDemoThread;
  URL: string;
begin
  If inProcess then exit;

  for URL in memo1.Lines do begin
    worker := TDemoThread.Create(True);  
    worker.FreeOnTerminate := True;
    worker.URL := URL;
    worker.List := Data;
    worker.Tracker := Fetchers;
    Fetchers.Add( worker );
  end;

  InProcess := True;

  for worker in Fetchers do
    worker.Start;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.SetInProcess(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if Value = InProcess then exit; // form already is in this mode

  FInProcess := Value;

  memo1.ReadOnly := Value;
  StartButton.Enabled := not Value;
  if Value then begin
     Memo2.Lines.Clear;
     Data.Clear;
  end;

  Timer1.Delay := 500; // twice per second
  Timer1.Enabled := Value;

  If not Value then  // for future optimisation - make immediate mode change 
     FlushData;      // when last worker thread quits, no waiting for timer event

  If not Value then
     ShowMessage('Work complete');
end;

procedure TfrmMain.Timer1Timer(const Sender: TObject);
begin
  FlushData;

  if Fetchers.Count <= 0 then
     InProcess := False;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FlushData;
begin
  Data.LockList;  // next two operations should go as non-interruptible atom
  try
    Memo2.Lines.AddStrings( Data.ToArray() );
    Data.Clear;
  finally
    Data.UnLockList;
  end;
end;

procedure TDemoThread.Execute;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  try 
    lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      lHTTP.ReadTimeout := 30000;
      lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;

      S := ExtractDelimitedString( lHTTP.Get('https://instagram.com/' + URL) );

      List.Add( S );
    finally
      lHTTP.Destroy;
    end;
  finally
    Tracker.Remove( Self );
  end;
end;
```

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TThreadList
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TStrings.AddStrings

PS. Personally, I'd also use OmniThreads Library, as it generally makes maintaining data-generating threads easier. For example just managing how many threads did you created becomes setting one property and determining when all threads complete their work is another oneliner. You really should not create a thousand of threads to fetch all the URLs, instead you should have 10-20 threads in a `Thread Pool` that would take the URLs from a `Input Queue` and fetch them one after another. I suggest you reading about OTL's `Parallel For` and `Fork-Join` patterns at http://otl.17slon.com/tutorials.htm - it would allow making such an application more concise and easier to write. `Pipeline` pattern would probably be even better match for this task - since you anyway prepare URLs list as a source collection. Half the scaffolding in `StartButtonClick` would be gone, and the whole `TDemoThread` class too.

Comment: Thanks, as you said its a bad design, i looked up for OTL, its good and i'll try to implement pipeline pattern.

Comment: @Thunderx you would have to write some boilerplate to populate AND then finalize source collection (https://github.com/gabr42/OmniThreadLibrary/issues/76). With parallel-For pattern that is not so (https://github.com/gabr42/OmniThreadLibrary/issues/55), but you would have to add some global variable for results-receiving collection (in pipeline it is given to your action-function in its params).

Comment: you would probably also have to google how to keep Memo2 scrolled to last line, it is not hard but you would have to do it after every adding new lines

Comment: have a look here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153277/how-to-use-pipleline-pattern-in-delphi?noredirect=1#comment65657775_39153277]

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you never assign to the `List` member of the thread class:

```
type
  TDemoThread = class(TThread)
  private
    procedure Abort;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    List: TStringList; <-- never assigned to, hence always nil
  end;
```

Hence the access violation.

It looks like you are trying to pass the contents of `memo1` to the thread. I would do that like so:

```
type
  TDemoThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FData: TStringList;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TDemoThread.Create(Data: TStrings);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FData := TStringList.Create;
  FData.Assign(Data);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

destructor TDemoThread.Destroy;
begin
  FData.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TDemoThread.Execute;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  i: integer;
  X: TStrings;
begin
  inherited;
  if Terminated then
    Exit;

  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  X := TStringList.Create;
  lHTTP.ReadTimeout := 30000;
  lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;

  for i := 0 to FData.Count - 1 do
    try
      X.Text := lHTTP.Get('https://instagram.com/' + FData[i]);
      S := ExtractDelimitedString(X.Text);
      X.Clear;
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          frmMain.Memo2.Lines.Add(FData[i] + ' : ' + S);
        end);
    finally
    end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.StartButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TDemoThread.Create(memo1.Lines);
end;
```

It is pointless to create suspended and then immediately start. It is also not permitted to hold a reference to a `FreeOnTerminate` thread after it has started so I removed that.

The code in `TDemoThread.Execute` leaks, unless you are running exclusively on an ARC platform. And the try/finally is pointless. And you don't need a string list to hold a single `string`. Assuming you aren't using ARC it should be:

```
procedure TDemoThread.Execute;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  i: integer;
  S: string;
begin
  if Terminated then
    Exit;

  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    lHTTP.ReadTimeout := 30000;
    lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;

    for i := 0 to FData.Count - 1 do
    begin
      S := ExtractDelimitedString(lHTTP.Get('https://instagram.com/' + FData[i]));
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          frmMain.Memo2.Lines.Add(FData[i] + ' : ' + S);
        end);
    end;
  finally
    lHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, first problem solved, now when i press start i get only one result in the Memo2 then it stops and the Thread Exit in the EventsLog.

Comment: I'm not planning to debug your entire program for you (which I cannot see). I answered the question you asked. And actually quite a lot more. Might I suggest that you move on from this question and continue debugging your code.